# A homeomorphism essentially takes a topological space into open subspace of the real?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, open-map

I've been question myself if the subspace of the real where we map a topological space needs to be necessarily open since the function that do this map is bijective and continuous, someone can help me please ?

Comment: Your question is so broad that it has trivial counterexamples: the subspace of the reals where we map a 1 point topological space is just 1 real number, which does not form an open set.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Silly” counterexample: $[0,1]$ embeds into $\Bbb R$ through homeomorphism to the non-open $[0,1]$.

Less trivial example: every finite dimensional real normed vector space, say of dimension $n$, embeds (with the norm topology) into $\Bbb R^k$ for $k\gt n$ as a proper closed and nonopen subset.

So, the answer is no. Continuity does not imply openness of the image I’m afraid. Knowing when an image is open is in general a difficult task, and theorems related to this (e.g. the open mapping theorem for Banach spaces) are quite important (since it is in general false).